# Furthest points away in 3D point cloud

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to figure out the best way to get the furthest two points in a point cloud. In 2d it can be done by finding the convex hull `O(NlogN)` and then some sort of antipodal point search say using rotating calipers in `O(N)`.

What would be the best way in 3D ?
I can see that you can still use the 3d convex hull and then possibly brute force. Assuming the hull has h points then it would be `O(h*(h-1)/2)` which is `O(h^2)`. In the worst case scenario whereby `N=h` that would be `O(N^2)`.

Can something better be done ?

Comment: For reference (the worst case is still quadratic): https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00615026/file/malandain-ijcga-2002.pdf

Comment: @MBo That is what I also said in my post above. I've also skimmed through the same paper and dont see really any much differrence with a brute force approach and the calculation of what they call a double normal unless you stop at some point where you get an approximate diameter.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of this one: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109406/find-two-points-in-a-point-cloud-with-the-maximum-distance

Comment: @CornelisdeMooij There are plenty of 2D answers out there but nothing really that focuses on 3D. As I mentioned the 2D solution is indeed much simpler.